# Acumulativo del año y mes actual SQL

Tags: sql-server, base-de-datos, sql

Tengo una consulta sin concluir, uso la siguiente consulta SQL para retornar los pagos por meses registrados:

```
SELECT MONTH(fecha_del_deposito) AS mes, 
SUM(importe) as monto FROM pago_cliente WHERE fecha_del_deposito
```

Esta es la tabla (Solo un muestreo de algunos datos):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y me da como resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero de ultima hora cambio todo, necesito que me retorne **solo el acumulado del año y mes actual**, algo asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ya que la anterior consulta me daba los de **todos los años**.

Gracias...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En este caso no hace falta agrupar nada:

```
SELECT 
       MONTH(NOW()) AS mes, 
       SUM(importe) as monto 
FROM 
       pago_cliente 
WHERE
       MONTH(fecha_del_deposito) = MONTH(NOW())
       AND YEAR(fecha_del_deposito) = YEAR(NOW())
GROUP BY 1;
```

Comment: El having actúa sobre las columnas que tienen funciones. en este caso sobre SUM(importe). Corrige la respuesta por favor, y agrega la clausula del año.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, lamentablemente cometí el error de poner 'BETWEEN' en esta pregunta, ya modifique el post. mas aparte, necesito que sea de forma dinámica el saber que mes es el actual, ya que va enfocado para  un sistema...Como "Curdate"

Comment: Ahora la edito para que actue con el mes actual

Answer (score 1):

Si lo que necesitas es filtar solo por el año y mes actual, debes usar dicha condición en tu where, es decir cambiarlo. Con getdate() obtienes la fecha actual del SQL.

```
SELECT 
       MONTH(fecha_del_deposito) AS mes, 
       SUM(importe) as monto 
FROM 
       pago_cliente 
WHERE 
       Year(fecha_del_deposito) = Year(getdate()) AND  
       Month(fecha_del_deposito) = Month(getdate())
GROUP BY 
       mes
```

Saludos.